# SQLAlchemy: Get bind parameters from sql dynamically

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to use pd and sqlalchemy to run all the sql files in a directory. Currently I can load the text of a sql file into a `sqlalchemy.sql.text` object, and send that directly to `pd.read_sql`. What should I use to locate the bind parameters within my sql script so that I can prompt the user for them?

```py
import sys, os, pandas as pd, re, sqlalchemy as sa

os.chdir(sys.argv[1])
os.mkdir("out")

uname = input("Username >>> ")
passw = input("Password >>> ")
engine = sa.create_engine(f"oracle+cx_oracle://{uname}:{passw}@PROD/?encoding=UTF-8&nencoding=UTF-8")

for filename in os.listdir('.'):
    if not re.match(filename,r".*\.sql"): continue #Ignore non-sql files. 
    print("Executing",filename)
    with open(filename,"r") as my_file:
        sql = sa.text(''.join(filename.readlines()))

        ### Something goes here ###

        df = pd.read_sql(''.join(my_file.readlines()),engine)
        df.to_excel(f"./out/{filename}",filename,index=False)
```

My current best guess is to read through the file line-by-line with a regex that finds things that look like bind params, but I feel like there should be a better way.

Comment: Tools like SQL\*Plus prompt for [substitution variables](https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/post/sql*plus-substitution-variables-define-variables-and-parameters-in-sql-queries), not bind variables.  If you want an example of prompting for substitution variables, see [sample_env.py](https://github.com/oracle/python-oracledb/blob/v1.1.0/samples/sample_env.py#L171-L204).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can obtain the names of the bind parameters from the compiled query:

```
>>> q = text('select id, name from users where name = :p1 and age > :p2')
>>> q.compile().params
{'p1': None, 'p2': None}
```

In the resulting dictionary, the keys correspond to the bind parameter names.  The values are `None` until values are bound.